# Mouse and keyboard always get input althoughtI don't do anything

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm coding a game with SFML library. I have some code to do when I press key and mouse click

I use this:
`Sf::keyBoard::isKeyPressed`
And this:
`Sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed`

But somehow there code always run every frame although I don't click or press anything.

Is my computer wrong or something else?

Comment: Please show us a minimal reproducable example, or at least any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
            {
                _isGameNotStarted = false;
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            {
                p->playerMoveR(_isGameNotStarted);
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            {
                p->playerMoveL(_isGameNotStarted);
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::R))
            {
                if (_isGameFinished == true)
                    resetLevel();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My pleasure. if you need more help you can check out my github repo: https://github.com/behluluysal/space-impact-sfml

There are some SFML projects